# Can i Find the Matrix from Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If i given eigenvector: 
$$V_1=\begin{pmatrix} {1\over \sqrt{3}}\\{1\over \sqrt{3}}\\{1\over \sqrt{3}}\end{pmatrix} , V_2=\begin{pmatrix} {1\over \sqrt{6}}\\{-2\over \sqrt{6}}\\{1\over \sqrt{6}}\end{pmatrix}  Space:\lambda=1 \\ V_3=\begin{pmatrix} {1\over \sqrt{2}}\\0\\{1\over \sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}Space: \lambda = 3$$

I know finding eigenvectors from matrix but how can i find Matix from those given vectors and $\lambda$s ?

Are those vectors orthonormal? (what are the properties of orthonormality ?)

Comment: You can't recover the matrix from the eigenpairs alone.

Comment: But i asked to find inverse of the matrix from it at the exam

Comment: I suggest you post the exact problem, maybe there's a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: Is the matrix symmetric? If so you can just use the eigenvalue decomposition $X = ZDZ^T$ where the columns of $Z$ are the eigenvectors and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with corresponding eigenvalues along the diagonal.

Comment: You cannot recover *the* original matrix since multiple matrices have the same eigenvalue/vector pairs.  However, one can easily find *a* matrix that has those eigenvalue/vector pairs.  (Consider a symmetric matrix).

Comment: it was exam question, and this is what i remember (i think there was notting more) and the question was Find $A^{-1}$ without finding Matrix A (hint: First expressing the eigendecomposition of vector products)

Comment: was something like this

Comment: @anortan I think it is unique if the matrix is diagonalizable. (The nonuniqueness comes from multiple possible Jordan forms.) But maybe I am confused? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: @noob I believe you are correct, but I'm a little out of my realm of certainty. :-)

Comment: Since it is an exam question, I suspect the third vector was $(\pm 1,0,\mp 1)/\sqrt{2}$.  That would give 3 orthonormal vectors of $A$.  The inverse matrix,  $A^{-1}$, would then be given by $1/\lambda_1 V_1 V_1^T + 1/\lambda_2 V_2 V_2^T + 1/\lambda_3 V_3 V_3^T$.  Note that I am using $V V^T$ to denote the outer product of two vectors.

Comment: @Louis $A^{-1}={1\over \lambda_1}V_1(V_1)^T+...$ is theorom or what? where did u come up with it ?

Comment: @Andy Here is a link to [matrix inverse eigendecomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix).  You'll have to scroll down a few sections. The formula $A = Q \Lambda Q^T$ is known as the spectral theorem or the principal axis theorem.  $Q$ is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$.  The expansion that I used is a technique used for constructing a matrix from projections or from projection operators.  Gilbert Strang uses it in Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 4th edition, Section 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see that the vectors $\{v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ is orthonormal meaning each has unit length($v_1.v_1 = v_1^T v_1 = 1$) and any pair($v_1.v_2 = v_1^Tv_2 = 0$) is orthogonal. so they for a basis for $R^3$ if you compose $A = v_1v_1^T + v_2v_2^T + 3v_3v_3^T$ as the linear combination three rank one matrices, then you can verify that $Av_1 = v_1, Av_2 = v_2$ and $Av_3 = 3v_3$ for  what this tells us is that the matrix has eigenvalues $1,1,3$ and the corresponding eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$

in fact, if $B = kv_1v_1^T + lv_2v_2^T + mv_3v_3^T,$ then the matrix $B$ has eigenvalues $k,l,m$ we can use this fact and that $A^{-1}$ has eigenvalues $1, 1, 1/3$(reciprocals of the eigenvalues of $A$) you have   $$ A^{-1} = v_1v_1^T + v_2v_2^T + {1 \over3}v_3v_3^T$$